# Place Legend above Epilog

Tags: plotting, graphics, legending

I am currently struggling with a problem which I haven't seen answered anywhere else.

I want to make a `ListDensityPlot` graph in which I need to draw some rectangles above the graph (I used `Epilog`, no problem here), but I also want to place the legend over that Epilog. However, when I do it (using `Placed`), the legend lays behind the Epilog, and thus is invisible...

Is there any way I can solve this?

If you need any other details, I can provide them.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: what I want is something like this:

```
f[x_, y_] := x^2 + y^2

fTab = Flatten[Table[{x, y, f[x, y]}, {x, -1, 1, 0.1}, {y, -1, 1, 0.1}], 1];

Rec = Epilog -> {Directive[LightGray],Rectangle[{-1, -0}, {-0.5, -1}],Rectangle[{-0.5, -1}, {0.5, -0.5}],Rectangle[{1, 0}, {0.5, -1}]};

Leg = PlotLegends -> Placed[BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {-1, 1}}, LegendLayout -> "ReversedRow", LegendMarkerSize -> 200, LegendLabel -> Placed["f(x,y)", Left], LabelStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 15]], {0.5, 0.1}]

ListDensityPlot[fTab, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", Evaluate[Rec], Evaluate[Leg]]
```

Comment: Could you please provide the code you are using so it would be a bit clearer what you are after? It seems like you could use function  `Labeled`

Comment: @E.Doroskevic I updated the question with an example of what I need.

Comment: Just to clarify, you want the legend to be above your `ListDensityPlot` that's it?

Comment: Yes, it is exactly that. I want it inside the plot and above the gray rectangles in there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `Show` instead of `Epilog` to add on the rectangles, and the legend will stay on top.

```
Show[
  ListDensityPlot[..., PlotLegends -> ...]
  Graphics[{...}]
]
```

Comment: What is the concept (general rule) behind this ordering?

Comment: @Alan I don't know.  In general, `Epilog` comes on top of the `Graphics` content.  But once you have a legend, you're working with a `Legended` object that contains `Graphics` inside, not a bare `Graphics`.  It would appear that `Epilog` also goes on top of the legend.  By using `Show`, we put the rectangles in the main content instead of `Epilog`.  `Show` *can* combine `Legended` objects as well.  It will combine the Graphics within, and use (potentially nested) Legended outside.